# select( ) is returning positive value only once

Tags: c, sockets, embos, select-function

The select function is returning +ve value when some packets reach the UDP port as expected. But this happens only once. From second time when a packet is received on the UDP port, the function is not responding for that. But in the first time after receiving the UDP packet if I do a sendto() on the same socket, the select function is responding. What would be the reason for this behaviour?

The code:

```
while (true)
{
   IP_FD_ZERO (&readFD);
   IP_FD_SET  (ipSock, &readFD);

   if (select( &readFD, NULL, NULL, 2000 ) > 0)
   {
      if (IP_FD_ISSET( ipSock, &readFD ))       //activity on UDP socket
      {
         addrlen   = sizeof(SocketAddrIn_t);
         noOfbytes = recvfrom( ipSock, 
                              (char*)ipRxBuffer, 
                              sizeof(ipRxBuffer), 
                              0, 
                              (SocketAddr_t *)&from, 
                              (int*)&addrlen );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What platform are you coding for...???  I'm not familiar with IP_FD_ISSET or with a select() with only 4 parameters...

Comment: EMBOS OS and using EMBOS-IP stack

Answer (score 1):

```
select( &readFD, NULL, NULL, 2000 )
```

Bzzt. The fourth parameter to `select()` is a `struct timeval *`, not an integer. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select).

Comment: I'm sorry that i didn't specify the environment. The API select which i use is from a stack supplier. It expects integer timeout.  For me the real problem i think is some flushing of the port is not happening because if i send some packet after the success of the select() function, the the select gives +ve value every time when I receive a UDP packet

Comment: The EMBOS select() example from the following URI does not exhibit that behavior... i.e. it does NO send between selects.  https://www.segger.com/admin/uploads/productDocs/UM07001_embOSIP.pdf